# adb device not listed for Gionee E7 mini

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have gone through numerous posts on this topic but none have helped me. I use Windows 7 and Eclipse IDE for Android app development. I am able to get my device listed for MotoG, so the version of Eclipse and SDK are up-to-date. I recently purchased a Gionee E7 mini and have been  unsuccessful in getting the adb device listed, and I have gone over hundreds of posts concerning the topic. This is what I have done so far:

> Blockquote

- Enable USB debugging in the phone(E7 mini).
- ADB version 1.0.31
- Changed android_winusb file to include the Hardware Ids for the phone(did not need to do this for Moto G)
- Tried changing the device input method to charge only/camera/File
- Tried adb kill-server and adb start-server
- Tried rebooting both the device and my system
- Tried the Universal ADB installer
- Android ADB Interface appears in Device Manager(without any exclamation) and the drivers show that they are updated

In some posts, "Android ADB Composite Interface" was shown in device manager but my system shows "Android ADB Interface". The RSA key fingerprint popup does not appear in the phone. The "adb devices" does not list any device. I found the drivers online and I do not know if the issue lies with them but after giving the address of the drivers, the system gave a message that the drivers are up-to-date.

Can anybody guess the problem. I will be really grateful.

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: which OS you are using in your PC? whats your Android device Hardware Id?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 in my PC. My Android device Hardware Id is USB\VID_271D&PID_0C03&REV_0216&MI_01 and USB\VID_271D&PID_0C03&MI_01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//add your hardware id in `adb_usb.ini` file

you just need to add the 0x2207 vendor id in “adb_usb.ini” from your `.android` folder

if file not found create it

```
 C:\Users\Compname\.android\adb_usb.ini


# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

0x2207
0X2021
```

try restart adb and run it

Comment: I created the file that you suggested. I also tried adding hardware id to the adb_usb.ini file. But the list of devices attached comes blank.

Comment: Thanks Padma, you made my day...My Vendor Id was 0x271D...Just this little change and it solved the problem...Thanks again :)