# android ADB not recognizing any devices

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, adb

I am trying to work with Android development, but I cannot get any android device to work with Eclipse. I try manually checking the devices in the command line by calling ADB devices, and it shows no connected devices.

I have tried with both a Galaxy Note and an Android phone and neither are recognized. I have all the device drivers installed and USB debugging turned on for each of the devices.

Is it possible that I do not have something configured correctly with my initial install of eclipse or the android tools, or perhaps need to download more software from the SDK?

I have read through many other questions but they are specific to a type of device not working, my issue is that no devices are being recognized.

Thanks.

Comment: which OS your are using?

Comment: try this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/23739599/1012284

Comment: The computer is Windows 7. The phone and tablet run android 4.1.2

Comment: Make sure they are appearing in Device Manager as a `ADB` device and try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but it still did not show either device.

Comment: I managed to get the phone recognized at least by doing a manual update of the ADB from the command line, but I still cannot get the tablet to connect. Does anyone know where I can find drivers for Samsung Galaxy Note® 10.1 (Wi-Fi)? I cannot find them on their website and that may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your device drivers are correctly installed?
Your device must be visible in device manager in Portable Devices category or something like that.
You can download drivers for Samsung devices here : http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The phone worked after doing a manual update for the abd so going to the command line where it was located and doing abd update.

The tablet was a different issue, apparently it needed samsung kies to be installed to communicate with the device.

So everything is working now.